# Trying to create a simple parallax effect in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I'm learning JS and JQ and I'm working on a simple parallax effect and I need help to get him right.
Here is the code: http://codepen.io/ronka/pen/JGxxBb.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('section[data-type="parallax"]').each(function(){
    var $bgobj = $(this);
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var $yPos = -($(window).scrollTop()- $bgobj.offset().top);
        console.log($(this));
        $bgobj.css('background-position','50% ' + $yPos +'px');
    });
  });
});
```

As you can see when you scroll you see the red background. I don't want it to show the red background just the image. what is the solution?

Comment: So why did you set the background color to red?

Comment: so i can see where there is no background image.

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('section[data-type="parallax"]').each(function(){
    var $bgobj = $(this);
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var yPos = $(window).scrollTop();
        $bgobj.css('background-position','50% -' + (yPos*0.4) +'px');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: look at the bottom one: http://codepen.io/ronka/pen/JGxxBb
it works only for the top sections.

Comment: It depends your screen size. You can adapt the parallax effect with this `-' + (yPos*0.4) +'px'`. It means when you scroll 1px, your images scroll -0.4px. So set down this value and your parallax effect will be reduced. Try with this instead `-' + (yPos*0.2) +'px'`.

Comment: it does work but if add few more sections the red background will appear again. i want to find solution that will work in all the platforms and sizes.